# numpy: multiply arrays without broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know if the title of the question makes sense, but I couldn't think of a better title.

Please consider the following scenario: I have two numpy arrays `a` and `b`, `b` has shape `(2, 2, 5)` and `a` has shape `(5,)`. I would like to multiply each element of `a` by each **2x2 ARRAY** in `b`, I **DON'T** want to multiply each element in `a` by each **ELEMENT** in each 2x2 array in `b`, which is what happens if I simply do `a * b`

The following code demonstrates my problem and my desired result:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)


class MyClass:
    def __mul__(self, other):
        print(f'{type(self).__name__} * {other}')
        return other

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print(f'{other} * {type(self).__name__}')
        return other


a = np.full((5,), MyClass())
b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2, 2, 5))

a * b
# MyClass * -0.6169610992422154
# MyClass * 0.24421754207966373
# ...
# MyClass * 0.5456532432247481
# MyClass * 0.7652823812722331

# Desired result:
[ai * bi for ai, bi in zip(a, np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0))]
# MyClass * [[-0.6169611  -0.45481479]
#  [-0.28436546  0.12239237]]
# ...
# MyClass * [[ 0.55995162  0.75186527]
#  [-0.25949849  0.76528238]]

# EDIT: Solution suggested by "Guimoute", does the same as a * b but also introduces addition (not a solution).
b @ a
# -0.6169610992422154 * MyClass
# 0.24421754207966373 * MyClass
# ...
# 0.5456532432247481 * MyClass
# 0.7652823812722331 * MyClass

c = np.split(np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0).reshape(-1, 2), 5)
# c is now a list of numpy arrays, with length = 5

a * c
# Raises an exception
# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (5,2,2)
```

**EDIT:** I should probably clarify that what I'm asking for is a numpy solution, rather than one involving a python loop ie: `[ai * bi for ai, bi in zip(a, np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0))]`.

**EDIT:** I added the suggestion by "Guimoute", involving matmul @ operator, which as can be seen is clearly not a solution.

**EDIT:** To address complaints that it was hard to verify potential solutions without having to check the order of some printed outputs I have added the following example which includes a function to check whether what a function does is a solution:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)


class MyClass:
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self


def solution_involving_python_loop(a, b):
    return np.array([ai * bi for ai, bi in zip(a, np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0))])

def is_valid_solution(func):
    return func(a, b).ndim == 1


a = np.full((5,), MyClass())
b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2, 2, 5))


print(is_valid_solution(solution_involving_python_loop))
# True
```

**EDIT:** In response to "hpaulj"'s answer I have added the following example, which does a bit more than just multiply by an array of references to the same object which doesn't do anything. Here I again try to clarify the difference between the standard numpy multiplication and the type of multiplication that I am looking for

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)


class Symbol:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Mul(self, other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return Mul(other, self)


class Mul:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.a} * {self.b}'


a = np.array([Symbol(chr(i)) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('a') + 5)])
b = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 2, 5))

# multiplication with broadcasting
broadcast_result = a * b
print(broadcast_result)
# [[[a * 47 b * 83 c * 38 d * 53 e * 76]
#   [a * 24 b * 15 c * 49 d * 23 e * 26]]
#
#  [[a * 30 b * 43 c * 30 d * 26 e * 58]
#   [a * 92 b * 69 c * 80 d * 73 e * 47]]]

# desired result
desired_result = np.array([ai * bi for ai, bi in zip(a, np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0))])
for x in desired_result:
    print(x)
# a * [[47 24]
#  [30 92]]
# b * [[83 15]
#  [43 69]]
# c * [[38 49]
#  [30 80]]
# d * [[53 23]
#  [26 73]]
# e * [[76 26]
#  [58 47]]
```

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve with this? What do you need this for? Could be there's a simpler approach.

Comment: @DominikStańczak The application is a bit too complicated to explain in a comment, but the array `b` represents the coefficients of a polynomial, and these coefficients can be scalars, they can be ndarrays or they can themselves be Polynomials, or any other type which supports the necessary arithmetic operations. If I evaluate the polynomial with polynomials as input arguments then I want the result to be a polynomial rather than an ndarray of polynomials, this is just one of the reasons why I need this kind of behavior, the full explanation is way to long for this comment.

Comment: If _"the application is a bit too complicated to explain in a comment"_, explain it in the body of the question. Also, complaining about the down votes in your question doesn't help. IMHO, it would be better to have that off of your question and focus in the problem you are trying to solve, providing us the maximum amount of information you can.

Comment: @accdias I have removed the complaint about the down-votes, although I think it was a valid complaint. As for adding an explanation of the application I will consider that, but I fear that it will transform the question into one about software architecture, and I am not really looking for alternative architecture solutions.

Comment: @Vinzent, votes are part of what makes Stack Overflow great. Don't take it personally. It is just the mechanism the forum has to push us toward improving our questions and answers. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: The tooltip for a downvote asks, "Is the question unclear?"  - and yeah, as it is stated, it sure seems to be that. That's not a problem with SO.

Comment: @DominikStańczak The question is definitely not unclear, I think the problem is that people don't take their time to read it.

Comment: @Vinzent, IMHO again, you are expending too much time thinking about the votes. Instead, try to focus on your question. Most of the things that are obvious to us, are not so to others. If people are down voting your question, go back and try to improve it. I'm pretty sure those who down voted it, will be more than glad to remove their votes, or even up vote the question, once they think it is clear enough and well-formed.

Comment: @accdias don't have a problem with that I just don't see how to improve it and when people don't comment on what they think should be improved it is hard for me to guess what people might be unsatisfied with.

Comment: It would probably help if you could create an example that one can tinker with, and compare to the required output without having to rely on inspecting the order of a bunch of printed messages, just like @Murali tried to do in their answer.

Comment: @DominikStańczak sure I can do that, you just need to replace `return other` with `return self` and then see if the result is a 1-dimensional array. I will add an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Split `b` into an array (with dtype=object) containing all the 2x2 arrays

```
c = np.empty((5,), dtype=object)
c[:] = np.split(np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0).reshape(-1, 2), 5)
# c is now an object array of numpy arrays, with length = 5

a * c
# MyClass * [[-0.6169611  -0.45481479]
#  [-0.28436546  0.12239237]]
# ...
# MyClass * [[ 0.55995162  0.75186527]
#  [-0.25949849  0.76528238]]
```

Not a solution that I like, but nobody seems to have a better one.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)


class MyClass:
    def __mul__(self, other):
        print(f'{type(self).__name__} * {other}')
        return other

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print(f'{other} * {type(self).__name__}')
        return other


a = np.full((5,), MyClass())
b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2, 2, 5))

your_sol = np.array([ai * bi for ai, bi in zip(a, np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0))])

your_required_array = np.moveaxis(a*b, -1, 0).astype(float)
```

Comment: I know, you specifically asked without broadcasting, but this is to show that you can still do it with broadcasting.

Comment: No this is not a solution, it has the same problem, you can try it yourself using the code that I provided.

Comment: I get same as ```[ai * bi for ai, bi in zip(a, np.moveaxis(b, -1, 0))]```

Comment: The numeric result when using floats is obviously the same, but that is not the point. Try `a = np.full((5,), MyClass())` instead and you will see the difference.

Comment: I updated  with ```a = np.full((5,), MyClass())```

Comment: And you also changed your answer without keeping the original, removing the context needed to understand the comments I wrote. Besides I mentioned explicitly in my question that I was looking for a solution not involving a python loop.

Comment: I just replaced a with class (previous lt was floats) and removed einsum). This did not change my proposed solution significalty. Where is the loop in ```np.moveaxis(a*b, -1, 0).astype(float)``` ?

Comment: The "solution" `your_required_array = np.moveaxis(a*b, -1, 0).astype(float)` is not a solution, it does exactly what I said that I don't want. It does the same as when I do `a * b` in my question.

Comment: I guess this solution doesn't meet @Vinzent's requirements because the actual use case has a more sensible multiplication operation than simply taking on the other object's value? If you actually compare `your_sol` and `your_required_array`, the values are identical.

Comment: @DominikStańczak That is exactly right!. The `MyClass` is just a dummy object used to show how the multiplication is done, element by element or array by array.

Comment: Then I guess the issue is that your question lacks an actual minimal verifiable example of the behavior you want, which is why I found the whole question hellishly confusing! It's going to be pretty difficult to get an answer that way.

Comment: What do you mean that my question "lacks an actual minimal verifiable example" I show in my code (in the comments) what the output is, there is a line where it says "Desired result..." and beneath that I show a solution involving a python loop and I show what the resulting output is. Anyone can copy my code and try a solution to see if the output matches my "Desired result".

Comment: In other words, `MyClass` is not a sufficient approximation of your actual use case - it doesn't convey all the requirements. As done here, @Murali got to the same numerical values that your "Desired output" did, which I'd also take for a good answer to the question as asked. But that's mostly an artifact of the pretty nonsensical multiplication operation in the example.

Comment: @DominikStańczak My reasoning was that making the `MyClass` actually do something similar to the actual use case would make the question a lot harder to follow and actually distract from my actual question. in my oppinion it should be perfectly clear that `MyClass` simply shows what is being multiplied, and that I desire the arrays along the last axis of `b` to be multiplied by the elements in `a` rather than broadcasting...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a still puzzled about the distinction between the two kinds of multiply.  Off hand they sound the same.  May the fact that `a` is object dtype matters.  But, do you realize what your `a` actually is?

Let's add a repr to your class:

```
In [122]: class MyClass:
     ...:     def __mul__(self, other):
     ...:         print(f'{type(self).__name__} * {other}')
     ...:         return other
     ...: 
     ...:     def __rmul__(self, other):
     ...:         print(f'{other} * {type(self).__name__}')
     ...:         return other
     ...:     def __repr__(self):
     ...:         return f'<{id(self)}>'
     ...: 
In [123]: MyClass()
Out[123]: <140080214874240>
In [124]: MyClass()
Out[124]: <140080207167392>
In [125]: a = np.full((5,), MyClass())
In [126]: a
Out[126]: 
array([<140080207226960>, <140080207226960>, <140080207226960>,
       <140080207226960>, <140080207226960>], dtype=object)
```

Notice the `a` has 5 references to the SAME object.  An array with 5 different objects:

```
In [127]: a1 = np.array([MyClass() for _ in range(5)])
In [128]: a1
Out[128]: 
array([<140080340066944>, <140080340068816>, <140080340066368>,
       <140080205271872>, <140080205271488>], dtype=object)
```

Let's change it further to show the id in the multiply:

```
In [135]: class MyClass:
     ...:     def __mul__(self, other):
     ...:         print(f'{self} * {other}')
     ...:         return other
     ...: 
     ...:     def __rmul__(self, other):
     ...:         print(f'{other} * {self}')
     ...:         return other
     ...:     def __repr__(self):
     ...:         return f'<{id(self)}>'

In [138]: a*b
<140080213575568> * 0
<140080213575568> * 1
<140080213575568> * 2
<140080213575568> * 3
...
<140080213575568> * 19
Out[138]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],

       [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]], dtype=object)
```

and when the objects differ, we see the repeated pattern

```
In [139]: a1*b
<140080187967328> * 0        # 1
<140080187966320> * 1
<140080187967712> * 2
<140080187966368> * 3
<140080187968960> * 4
<140080187967328> * 5        # 2
<140080187966320> * 6
<140080187967712> * 7
<140080187966368> * 8
<140080187968960> * 9
<140080187967328> * 10       # 3
<140080187966320> * 11
<140080187967712> * 12
<140080187966368> * 13
<140080187968960> * 14
<140080187967328> * 15       # 4
<140080187966320> * 16
<140080187967712> * 17
<140080187966368> * 18
<140080187968960> * 19
Out[139]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],

       [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]], dtype=object)
```

### edit

So what you want is more like this list comprehension:

```
In [142]: [a1[i]*b[:,:,i] for i in range(5)]
<140080187967328> * [[ 0  5]
                     [10 15]]
<140080187966320> * [[ 1  6]
                     [11 16]]
<140080187967712> * [[ 2  7]
                     [12 17]]
<140080187966368> * [[ 3  8]
                     [13 18]]
<140080187968960> * [[ 4  9]
                     [14 19]]
```

In [139] <140080187967328> multiplies [0,5,10,15] as well.

If we make a (5,) object array from `b`, we get the same pairings:

```
In [143]: b1 = np.empty(5,object); b1[:] = [b[:,:,i] for i in range(5)]
In [144]: a1*b1
<140080187967328> * [[ 0  5]
 [10 15]]
<140080187966320> * [[ 1  6]
 [11 16]]
<140080187967712> * [[ 2  7]
 [12 17]]
<140080187966368> * [[ 3  8]
 [13 18]]
<140080187968960> * [[ 4  9]
 [14 19]]
Out[144]:                         # same as b1
array([array([[ 0,  5],
              [10, 15]]), array([[ 1,  6],
                                 [11, 16]]), array([[ 2,  7],
                                                    [12, 17]]),
       array([[ 3,  8],
              [13, 18]]), array([[ 4,  9],
                                 [14, 19]])], dtype=object)
```

Math on object dtype arrays takes place a list comprehension speeds.

Comment: MyClass is just a dummy object used to show what it is being multiplied by, I know that the way I set up the example the array `a` just contains references to the same object, this is not my actual application. I only created MyClass to have a way of showing what the elements of `a` are being multiplied by, a scalar or an array.

Comment: I have added another edit in an attempt to further clarify my question. In this edit I try again to show what the difference is between the two types of multiplication.

Comment: In response to your edit: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for, and I in fact posted that solution in an answer myself. I was just hoping that there was a "better"/"cleaner" solution, perhaps something built into numpy.

Comment: I added a object dtype version of `b` that pairs this with `a`.